# Assert equality between HashMap and MapWithDefault

Tags: java, groovy, junit

I am writing some jUnit tests, in which I need to assert equality between `groovy.lang.MapWithDefault` and `java.util.HashMap`:

```
assertEquals(lMapWithDefaultVar, lHashMapVar)
```

This gives me error as:

```
java.lang.AssertionError: expected:<groovy.lang.MapWithDefault@a7f4fa3a> but was:  <!-- here it shows HashMap contents -->
    at org.junit.Assert.fail(Assert.java:93)
    at org.junit.Assert.failNotEquals(Assert.java:647)
    at org.junit.Assert.assertEquals(Assert.java:128)
    at org.junit.Assert.assertEquals(Assert.java:147)
    at org.junit.Assert$assertEquals$0.callStatic(Unknown Source)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSiteArray.defaultCallStatic(CallSiteArray.java:53)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.callStatic(AbstractCallSite.java:157)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.callStatic(AbstractCallSite.java:169)
    at com.myPackage.MyClass(MyClass.groovy:156)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:601)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod$1.runReflectiveCall(FrameworkMethod.java:45)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:15)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod.invokeExplosively(FrameworkMethod.java:42)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.InvokeMethod.evaluate(InvokeMethod.java:20)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.RunBefores.evaluate(RunBefores.java:28)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.RunAfters.evaluate(RunAfters.java:30)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runLeaf(ParentRunner.java:263)
    at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:68)
    at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:47)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:231)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:60)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:229)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:50)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:222)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.RunBefores.evaluate(RunBefores.java:28)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.RunAfters.evaluate(RunAfters.java:30)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:300)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit4.runner.JUnit4TestReference.run(JUnit4TestReference.java:50)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.TestExecution.run(TestExecution.java:38)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:467)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:683)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.run(RemoteTestRunner.java:390)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.main(RemoteTestRunner.java:197)
```

How can I assert equality between `groovy.lang.MapWithDefault` and `java.util.HashMap`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like MapWithDefault is being a bit naughty and not obeying the [core equals implementation for map](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Map.html#equals(java.lang.Object)). It should just compare key/value pairs and should ignore the map implementation.

To workaround this, you could try

```
assertEquals(new HashMap(lMapWithDefaultVar), lHashMapVar)
```

Or maybe even just switching the order will use HashMap.equals(...) instead of MapWithDefault.equals(...). Eg:

```
assertEquals(lHashMapVar, lMapWithDefaultVar)
```

Comment: yep both worked. Stupid me. I was trying `assertEquals((HashMap)lMapWithDefaultVar, lHashMapVar)`. But it did not worked.

Comment: Switching the order will work but the meaning of the statement is not the same because `assertEquals(a,b)` means "I expect b to have the value of a".

Comment: @Gaël in which cases `assertEquals(a,b)` will differ from `assertEquals(b,a)`?

Comment: @Mahesha999 `assertEquals(a,b)` will invoke a's `equals()` method so the order matters. But `assertEquals(b,a)` will give a confusing error message in the junit logs if the test fails. So I guess my first suggestion is best.

Answer (score 1):

When using `assertEquals(m1, m2)` on two maps, you're using `m1.equals(m2)` method.

What does `groovy.lang.MapWithDefault#equals()` method does ? Not sure it returns `true` when comparing with a `HashMap` even if the content is the same.

You could compare `m1.entrySet()` with `m2.entrySet()` (which is the default behavior expected for a `Map` according to Javadoc).

Comment: Considering that MapWithDefault has not implemented `equals(....)` correctly. I'm not sure I'd trust comparing the two entry sets. There's a good chance that might fail too!